# Creating pdf from java (best library)

Tags: java, pdf

What is the best Java library for PDF work, process, parse, print and so on...

I found this one http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/download/print-pdf-java-oracle-2399266.html, but i am not sure about this is the best.

If someone has expereinces in this field, i would appreciate his answer based on his experiences. Thanks!

Comment: [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) to generate, [JPedal](http://www.jpedal.org/) to render. Also, this is clearly a polling question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used Apache FOP in a project to render a xslt (with fo). It worked very well.

Comment: To generate a xslt a very good tool is XF Designer (http://www.ecrion.com). They also have a own rendering server but it works fine with FOP.